# Read and view uploaded file in a new html page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

I  created an html page which takes in .csv files,reads the file and displays the content in a table in the same page using jquery.My requirement is to view the table on multiple html pages or next page(another html page) residing in my project folder.

Here is my upload page[image]

And here is my review page [image]

Here is my jquery code to read and display table content:

```
$(function () {
                       $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
                       var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
                       if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) 
                       {
                       if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                       var reader = new FileReader();
                       reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var table = $("<table />");                                              
                        var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");                          
                        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {                              
                            var row = $("#td");
                            var xd=$("#th");


                          row.append(xd);




                            var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                            for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                                var cell = $("<tr />");
                                cell.html(cells[j]); 

                                row.append(cell);
                            }
                           var vh=$("#ab");  

                           table.append(vh);
                            table.append(row);
                        }
                        $("#tab").html('');

                        $("#tab").append(table);                           
                    }
                    reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
            }
        });
    });
```

Experts please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to display the content on another HTML file after reading.

There are multiple solutions to your question. but what i would recommend is 
1) Read the file data and place it in Array or List.
2) use pageContext.setAttribute and set the list.
3) redirect to the HTML page you want to display.
4) List list = use pageContext.getAttribute("list").
5) Use this list to display the data.

Comment: Hi sachin, sorry but i'm new to jquery can you elaborate with some code please.Thank you